# Appending row to dataframe with concat()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined an empty data frame with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Weight', 'Sample'])
```

and want to append rows in a for loop like this:

```
for key in my_dict:
   ...
   row = {'Name':key, 'Weight':wg, 'Sample':sm}
   df = pd.concat(row, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

But I get this error

```
cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

If I use `df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)`, it works but it seems that `append` is deprecated. So, I want to use `concat()`. How can I fix that?

Comment: it would more efficient if you collect all the dicts in a list and concatenate once.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can transform your dict in pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Weight', 'Sample'])
for key in my_dict:
  ...
  #transform your dic in DataFrame
  new_df = pd.DataFrame([row])
  df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Concat needs a list of series or df objects as first argument.

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'the_key': 'the_value'}

for key in my_dict:
   row = {'Name': 'name_test', 'Weight':'weight_test', 'Sample':'sample_test'}
   df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(row, index=[key])], axis=1, ignore_index=True) 

print(df)
         0          1           2
the_key name_test   weight_test sample_test
```

Comment: concat  needs two data frame arguments

Answer (score 2):

As user7864386 suggested, the most efficient way would be to collect the `dict`s and to concatenate them later, but if you for some reason have to add rows in a loop, a more efficient way would be `.loc`, because that way you don't have to turn your `dict` into a single-row `DataFrame` first:

```py
    df.loc[len(df),:] = row
```

It's rather hard to benchmark this properly, because `%timeit` of that row will grow the `DataFrame` and make the call slower over time, while the alternative

```py
    pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(row)], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

does not mutate `df`, and `df = ...` can't be `%timeit`ed as it causes an `UnboundLocalError`. Running one `%timeit` before and one after the other one makes me assume a speed advantage of a factor of 2, though.