# Append rows to dataset if missing from declared dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to add or append rows with values listed in dictionary (if these values are missing from original dataset)

**Data**

```
ID      Date    Type    Cost
Alpha   Q1 2022 ok      1
Alpha   Q2 2022 ok      1
Alpha   Q3 2022 hi      1
Alpha   Q4 2022 hi      2
```

**Desired**

```
ID      Date    Type    Cost
Alpha   Q1 2022 ok      1
Alpha   Q2 2022 ok      1
Alpha   Q3 2022 hi      1
Alpha   Q4 2022 hi      2
Gamma   Q1 2022         0
Theta   Q1 2022         0
```

**Doing**

I am using the script below, however, this is not appending, but only maps the value if date matches.
Any suggestion is appreciated

```
#values =   {'Alpha': 'Q1 2022', 'Gamma':' Q1 2022', 'Theta': 'Q1 2022'}

df['ID']=out['Date'].map({'Alpha': 'Q1 2022', 'Gamma':' Q1 2022', 'Theta': 'Q1 2022' })

df1 = df1.merge(df, how='left').fillna({'Cost': 0})
```

Comment: Try `df.append(dict_like_pd_series, ignore_index=True)` or [`pd.concat([df, df_rows])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat). Both methods can append rows.

Comment: which of these are df and df1? merge add columns, you would need concat to append rows

Comment: I can't seem to find a previous post where I answered this.. What I did to solve this was to create a df with all the values you want, let's call that df 'required'. Then do a merge eg: pd.merge(final_df, required, how='right'). You'll probably want to play with the on= param depending on the columns/rows you want to enforce. Hope that makes sense..

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No not yet @bieboebap

Comment: I'd suggest writing (with code, explicitly) the input and the expected output. Right now it is unclear what is e.g. `out['Date']`, `df1`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us create a `delta` dataframe from the `items` of dictionary, then do a outer `merge` to append distinct rows

```
delta = pd.DataFrame(values.items(), columns=['ID', 'Date'])
df.merge(delta, how='outer')
```

---

```
      ID      Date Type  Cost
0  Alpha   Q1 2022   ok   1.0
1  Alpha   Q2 2022   ok   1.0
2  Alpha   Q3 2022   hi   1.0
3  Alpha   Q4 2022   hi   2.0
4  Gamma   Q1 2022  NaN   NaN
5  Theta   Q1 2022  NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

My test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],
                   'col2': [0.5, 0.75]})
values = {1: 0.5, 4: 2.0}
```

First get the keys of your dataframe:

```
existing_items = dict(zip(df.col1, df.col2))
```

Find the items in your dict that are not in the dataframe:

```
difference = set(values.items())-set(existing_items.items()
```

Make it a dictionary again:

```
diff_dict = dict(difference)
```

Results: {2: 0.75}

And then append those results to your pandas dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71132602/9611924

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. [pandas.dataframe.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is the right method to go with. What you missed was to create the correct table as it should look like (with regard to the columns *ID* and *Date). So let's do this again step by step.

Assuming, we have your dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'ID': 'Alpha', 'Date': 'Q1 2022', 'Type': 'OK', 'Cost': 1},
                   {'ID': 'Alpha', 'Date': 'Q2 2022', 'Type': 'OK', 'Cost': 1},
                   {'ID': 'Alpha', 'Date': 'Q3 2022', 'Type': 'hi', 'Cost': 1},
                   {'ID': 'Alpha', 'Date': 'Q4 2022', 'Type': 'hi', 'Cost': 2}])
```

Let's construct the desired dataframe. (You could also just construct a table with the missing rows but to me it looks like an easy pattern that you may want to scale.) For now I assume a pattern (`'alpha'`, `'beta'` for the column *ID* and 4 quarters per year):

```py
id_keys = ['Alpha', 'Beta']
date_years = [2022]

rows = []
for id in id_keys:
    # construct dates
    for y in date_years:
        for q in range(1, 5):
            rows.append({'ID': id, 'Date': f'Q{q} {y}'})
        
df_ideal = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

|  | ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alpha | Q1 2022 |
| 1 | Alpha | Q2 2022 |
| 2 | Alpha | Q3 2022 |
| 3 | Alpha | Q4 2022 |
| 4 | Beta | Q1 2022 |
| 5 | Beta | Q2 2022 |
| 6 | Beta | Q3 2022 |
| 7 | Beta | Q4 2022 |

Now go ahead and merge the actual table `df` with the just constructed, desired table `df_ideal`:

```py
df.merge(df_ideal, on=['ID', 'Date']).fillna({'Cost': 0})
```

|  | ID | Date | Type | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alpha | Q1 2022 | OK | 1.0 |
| 1 | Alpha | Q2 2022 | OK | 1.0 |
| 2 | Alpha | Q3 2022 | hi | 1.0 |
| 3 | Alpha | Q4 2022 | hi | 2.0 |
| 4 | Beta | Q1 2022 | NaN | 0.0 |
| 5 | Beta | Q2 2022 | NaN | 0.0 |
| 6 | Beta | Q3 2022 | NaN | 0.0 |
| 7 | Beta | Q4 2022 | NaN | 0.0 |

Answer (score 1):

This question and the above answers focus on merging two frames; however, have you tried concatenating them? It might be easier if the values for the type and cost column change for Gamma and Theta in the future. If you merge - you will get NaN. Here is how I would go about it,

a working notebook is located here- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10DCteuD02HVnYHRX8aZyq_Mi2IW6SAHz?usp=sharing

```
data1 = data.copy(deep=True) #copy given data 
values =   { 'Gamma':' Q1 2022', 'Theta': 'Q1 2022'} #I removed alpha
data2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=data1.columns)
data2['ID'] = values.keys()
data2['Date'] = data2['ID'].map(values)
((pd.concat([data1,data2])).reset_index(drop=True)).fillna({'Cost': 0,'Type':""})
```

The output I got is -

```
ID  Date    Type    Cost
0   Alpha   Q1 2022 OK  1
1   Alpha   Q2 2022 OK  1
2   Alpha   Q3 2022 hi  1
3   Alpha   Q4 2022 hi  2
4   Gamma   Q1 2022     0
5   Theta   Q1 2022     0
```

An attempt to functionalize the above to solve a common problem in retail ETL flow and automate will be -

```
def add_me(data1:pd.DataFrame,values:dict,COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) -> pd.DataFrame:
  """
  COL1,COL2 - ARE COLUMNS IN VALUE MAP,
  COL3,COL4 - FILL NA WITH ZERO with integer or space in case of string
  """
  data2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=data1.columns)
  data2[COL1] = values.keys()
  data2[COL2] = data2[COL1].map(values)
  return ((pd.concat([data1,data2])).reset_index(drop=True)).fillna({COL3: 0,COL4:""})
```

executing above, spits out:

```
ID  Date    Type    Cost
0   Alpha   Q1 2022 OK  1
1   Alpha   Q2 2022 OK  1
2   Alpha   Q3 2022 hi  1
3   Alpha   Q4 2022 hi  2
4   Gamma   Q1 2022     0
5   Theta   Q1 2022     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `set_index()` and using `reindex()` with a newly created MultiIndex.

```
cols = ['ID','Date'] #columns to include in MultiIndex.

df = df.set_index(cols) #set columns as MultiIndex

    (df.reindex(
    df.index.union(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(values.items(),names = cols)) #Create union with index created above and values dictionary
    )
.reset_index()
.fillna({'Type':'','Cost':0}))
```

Output:

```
      ID      Date Type  Cost
0  Alpha   Q1 2022   ok   1.0
1  Alpha   Q2 2022   ok   1.0
2  Alpha   Q3 2022   hi   1.0
3  Alpha   Q4 2022   hi   2.0
4  Gamma   Q1 2022        0.0
5  Theta   Q1 2022        0.0
```